# How can I access environment variable set in external bash script in Github Actions?

Tags: bash, github-actions

I try to add a Jira ticket validation for our repository and decided to do it with Github actions.

I have an external bash script that I run in one step which sets the result if a Jira ticket is found to an environment variable.

I have another step which tried to access this environment variable and fail/success the flow by the result.

However, I can't seem to make it work, I don't see the new environment variable configured in the bash script.

Some code:

script.sh:

```
...
echo "jira_ticket_exists=false" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
...
```

Github action step:

```
    - name: choose to reject or not
    id: jira_ticket_reject
    continue-on-error: true
    run: |
      env # searched for it also here - it doesn't exist.
      echo ${{ env.jira_ticket_exists }} # this returns nothing
      if [ ${{ env.jira_ticket_exists }} == "true" ]; then
        echo "Jira ticket found"
        exit 0
      else
        echo "Jira ticket not found"
        exit 1
      fi
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

thank you

Comment: Your script is writing to a file, not an environment variable. Also, env vars are only passed on to child processes, not to siblings or parents, in case that's what you assume.

Comment: Why use echo in the first place to set a env variable? Why not declare it right away? Im just currious, perhaps you have a good reason, but this seems needless.

Comment: If I understand GuiFalourd's answer correctly, it seems to be a configuration file actually. The "environment variable" in the question seems to be a red herring, at best the config file shows up as environment variables at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the same thing here and the problem seems related to the double quotes you used with the `$GITHUB_ENV`.

**In your shell script, instead of:**

`echo "jira_ticket_exists=false" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"`

**You should use:**

`echo "jira_ticket_exists=false" >> $GITHUB_ENV`

---

**Here is the demo I used if you want to check:**

- [Workflow file](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester28.yml)
- [Shell script](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/scripts/test_workflow28.sh)
- [Workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/5571415981?check_suite_focus=true) with env variable working as expected.

Comment: just to add a follow-up. In my flow, I also used "cd" to the script location and then ran it. which I think is also related to my original issue. after removing the CD and doing @GuiFalourd recommendation I managed to get it working. Thank you!